# Unable to install Octave in armhf - Error in loading `libopenblas.so.0`

Tags: 18.04, android, arm, shared-library, octave

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 (using the armhf [rootfs](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/bionic/current/) created by Canonical) in Termux in my mobile phone.

While installing octave (`sudo apt install octave`) I am getting the following error.

```
Setting up octave (4.2.2-1ubuntu1) ...    
/usr/bin/octave-cli: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 installed octave package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
  octave                                   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have run `octave --configure`, which again says

```
/usr/bin/octave-cli: error while loading shared libraries: libopenblas.so.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Permission denied
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? The package `libopenblas-dev` is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, the `libopenblas.so.0` has some issues.

To fix, use the following commands to replace OpenBLAS with BLAS (which is much slower, unfortunately).

1. `sudo apt install liblapack-dev liblas-dev gcc`
2. `sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-arm-linux-gnuabihf` (choose BLAS instead of OpenBlas)
3. `sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3-arm-linux-gnuabihf` (choose BLAS instead of OpenBlas)